# Имена священников

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как нужно записать в указателе имен, скажем, отца Андрея Андреева?

```
Андреев А.   
Андреев А. (отец)
о. Андрей Андреев
отец Андреев А.
```

или как-нибудь иначе?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Если о поминальных списках речь, то — *о. Андрей (Андреев)*. В других перечнях указывают сан или должность полностью. Так, например, среди духовенства Храма преподобной Евфросинии Великой княгини Московской (www.evfrosinia.ru) значатся: настоятель храма иеромонах Клавдиан, иерей Иоанн Боков, диакон Николай Тюрин...

Скобки, отделяющие мирскую часть имени, необязательны, но желательны в отношении к документу: страничка «Реквизиты» заканчивается полным именем настоятеля храма в Котлах — иеромонах Клавдиан (Сафонов).